# Exported File is not the same as file compiled in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, compilation, export

Whenever I export my Code to a jar file it does'nt work as I want it to. For example if I run it in Eclipse there is a gui with labels textfields and so on. But if I export it and then run it some textfields and labels are missing while some are shown. What could cause this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running SWT GUI from jar file is different (and faulty) but works perfectly running from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33220937/5221149)

Comment: See also: [Why the same font looks different in Java app run from Netbeans and run from Jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30958864/5221149)

Comment: In these threads there is not much help given